# MySQL query - condition (comparing strings) does not work

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has only got 1 Column 'Name' with 100 unique entries.

I need to find out if a given Value exists in that table.

I am using:

```
SELECT 1 FROM `tbl_names` WHERE `Name` = "Lisa"
```

MySQL returns an empty result, so no 0 for not found and no 1 for found, even though the given name is an entry in that table.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you want to `SELECT 1` ?

Comment: Are you sure about characters? Have you tried this one:
`SELECT 1 FROM "tbl_names" WHERE "Name" = 'Lisa'`

Comment: Try `TRIM()` and see if it works

Comment: So you are trying to return the result with Name = 'Lisa', is that correct?

Comment: The TRIM did it. Apparently each value had an "\r" at the end that was not visible from the phpmyadmin overview

Comment: Normally, select * from table_name where Name ='Lisa' should yield the result

Answer (score 1):

`select count(*) from tbl_name where name = 'Lisa'` - will return count of entries with `Lisa` in the column. You can do as before with `select 1`, and calculate results - zero size means no occurance

Comment: This returns Count 0

Comment: Maybe try with this `LOWER(`name`) = LOWER("Lisa")` instead of simple comparison - if name is lowercased... Other option is to call `select '>>' || name || '<<' from tbl_names where Name like '%Lisa%'` to see if there are some spaces in the name...

Comment: None of the names are lowercased and there are no spaces or anything in the Values.

Comment: Nevermind I missed "\r" that I could not see without actually clicking each of the values. I trim'ed the whole DB and now it seems to work. Thanks for the help. Much appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return as 0 or 1, I would suggest:

```
select (exists (select 1 from tbl_names where Name = 'Lisa')) as flag
```

This will not fix the problem that you describe -- but it will always return one row with a single column whose value is 0 or 1.

`'Lisa'` is not in the table.  You might try `where Name like '%Lisa%'`.

Comment: This returns Flag 0. If i try `where Name like '%Lisa%` I will get not only the name Lisa, but also other names containing Lisa

Comment: @LisaCleaver . . . The point of this answer is to return one row with one column.  Your data does not seem to have the name `'Lisa'` -- at least as you have typed it in the query.